# Doesn't index or extract the Document (.pdf .doc) from Remotely

Tags: solr, solrnet, apache-tika

I am using Solr 3.1, Apache Tika 0.9 and Solrnet 0.3.1 to index the
docuent like a .doc and .pdf file.

I have successfully index and extract document on locally using this
code

```
Startup.Init<Article>("http://k9server:8080/solr");
        ISolrOperations<Article> solr = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance <ISolrOperations<Article>>();
        string filecontent = null;
        using(var file = File.OpenRead(@"D:\\solr.doc")){
                    var response = solr.Extract(new ExtractParameters(file, "abcd1") {
                        ExtractOnly  = true,
                        ExtractFormat = ExtractFormat.Text,
            });
            filecontent = response.Content;
        }
        solr.Add(new Article() {
                ID  = "36",
                EMAIL = "1234",
                COMMENTS = filecontent,
                PRO_ID = 256
        });
        // commit to the index
        solr.Commit();
```

But I am facing the problem to extract or index the document from remotely using same code, I got the error :

```
The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error. 
SolrNet.Exceptions.SolrConnectionException was unhandled
```

**Message**

```
Apache Tomcat/6.0.32 - Error report HTTP Status 500 - org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.getRoot()Lorg/apache/poi/poifs/filesystem/DirectoryNode;

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.getRoot()Lorg/apache/poi/poifs/filesystem/DirectoryNode;
    at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.SummaryExtractor.parseSummaryEntryIfExists(SummaryExtractor.java:65)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.SummaryExtractor.parseSummaries(SummaryExtractor.java:57)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.OfficeParser.parse(OfficeParser.java:164)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:197)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:197)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser.parse(AutoDetectParser.java:135)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.extraction.ExtractingDocumentLoader.load(ExtractingDocumentLoader.java:196)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:55)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:129)
    at org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers$LazyRequestHandlerWrapper.handleRequest(RequestHandlers.java:238)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1360)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:356)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:252)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:864)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1665)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**Message**

```
org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.getRoot()Lorg/apache/poi/poifs/filesystem/DirectoryNode;    
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.getRoot()Lorg/apache/poi/poifs/filesystem/DirectoryNode;
            at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.SummaryExtractor.parseSummaryEntryIfExists(SummaryExtractor.java:65)
            at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.SummaryExtractor.parseSummaries(SummaryExtractor.java:57)
            at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.OfficeParser.parse(OfficeParser.java:164)
            at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:197)
            at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:197)
            at org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser.parse(AutoDetectParser.java:135)
            at org.apache.solr.handler.extraction.ExtractingDocumentLoader.load(ExtractingDocumentLoader.java:196)
            at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:55)
            at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:129)
            at org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers$LazyRequestHandlerWrapper.handleRequest(RequestHandlers.java:238)
            at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1360)
            at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:356)
            at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:252)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:864)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:579)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1665)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**Description**

```
The server encountered an internal error (org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.getRoot()Lorg/apache/poi/poifs/filesystem/DirectoryNode;

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.getRoot()Lorg/apache/poi/poifs/filesystem/DirectoryNode;
    at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.SummaryExtractor.parseSummaryEntryIfExists(SummaryExtractor.java:65)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.SummaryExtractor.parseSummaries(SummaryExtractor.java:57)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.OfficeParser.parse(OfficeParser.java:164)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:197)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:197)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser.parse(AutoDetectParser.java:135)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.extraction.ExtractingDocumentLoader.load(ExtractingDocumentLoader.java:196)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:55)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:129)
    at org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers$LazyRequestHandlerWrapper.handleRequest(RequestHandlers.java:238)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1360)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:356)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:252)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:864)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1665)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
) that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
  Source=SolrNet
  StackTrace:
       at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.PostStream(String relativeUrl, String contentType, Stream content, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
       at SolrNet.Commands.ExtractCommand.Execute(ISolrConnection connection)
       at SolrNet.Impl.SolrBasicServer`1.Send(ISolrCommand cmd)
       at SolrNet.Impl.SolrBasicServer`1.SendAndParseExtract(ISolrCommand cmd)
       at SolrNet.Impl.SolrBasicServer`1.Extract(ExtractParameters parameters)
       at SolrNet.Impl.SolrServer`1.Extract(ExtractParameters parameters)
       at SolrNetSample.Program.Main(String[] args) in E:\TestProject\SolrNetSample\SolrNetSample\SolrNetSample\Program.cs:line 38
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: System.Net.WebException
       Message=The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
       Source=System
       StackTrace:
            at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
            at HttpWebAdapters.Adapters.HttpWebRequestAdapter.GetResponse()
            at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.GetResponse(IHttpWebRequest request)
            at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.PostStream(String relativeUrl, String contentType, Stream content, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
```

Comment: Can you post the error log from the remote server? That may give some hints as to why it generated the 500.

Comment: I have post the error log just check out it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your remote server has two different versions of Apache POI on the classpath, that's why you're getting the exception you see

You should remove the older version of POI, and leave just the new jars that came with SOLR / Tika. See the [POI FAQ](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006) for how to identify the extra jar if you can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

If it works against your local Solr instance but not against another instance, then the other instance is probably not configured correctly.

Judging by the stack trace, it seems that the POI libraries are incorrect (maybe the wrong version). Make sure to copy all Tika JARs from the Solr 3.1.0 distribution.